# why do we need to numeric the categorical features in Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, cart

We know that we usually use `one-hot encoding` to numeric the `categorical feature` in Machine Learning (although not advised in tree). There are also many algorithms in Tree models to numeric the categorical feature like `CatBoost`, `LightBGM` e.t.c.

But why do we need numeric in Tree? It seems the definition of `Entropy`, `Gini impurity` are both available for the discrete variables and the decision tree algorithms like `ID3` and `C4.5` both work for the categorical feature. The only problem seems from the `regression tree`. Can anyone explain more on this party?

Comment: We don't need it, current algorithms work with both kinds of data

Comment: @gunes could I understand that numeric for Categorical feature is only needed for regression three? `CatBoost` and `LightGBM` consider the numeric of Categorical feature since they are both under the `GBDT` framework and GBDT is mostly for the regression tree (classification is also available but it is another story).

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52066/55122

Comment: The output type (regression vs classification) has nothing to do with what kinds of input (categorical vs continuous) are allowed.  And GBDT build regression trees anyway (since they are fitting to a gradient).

Comment: @BenReiniger then shoud GBDT numeric the categorical feature? Since the gradient of GBDT is the derivatives respect to the output $f(x)$ but not the categorical feature $x$ itself. So I think it is the same case of regression tree.

Comment: @gunes the same question asked above, should GBDT numeric the categorical feature?

Comment: @BenReiniger I understand that all the tree models (including GBDT) can directly deal with the categorical features. And the motivation of numeric is that the categories of feature may not be comparable and we need to give them a numeric value to make them ordered to process the optimal splitting. Is it right?

Comment: The motivation for numerically encoding categorical features is usually one of: (1) your package doesn't handle categoricals natively, (2) your package handles categoricals by brute force and it's too slow, (3) your categoricals are actually ordinal, or _maybe_ (4) encoding loses information that actually improves your bias/variance tradeoff.

Comment: e@BenReiniger Take an example of binary splitting in LightGBM, we want to use a approximate splitting rather than the brute force to save the time cost. However the arbitrary order of samples respect to the  categorical feature does not make sense and we numeric them to give them a reasonable order before the binary splitting, am I right? By the way, GBDT can directly deal with the categorical features? I just want to confirm my confusion : )

Comment: @BenReiniger I asked an other question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508241/different-numeric-value-of-the-same-category-in-target-statistics-of-catboost  Does it make sense the same category in different samples has different numeric value? e.g. $x^2_4 = "cat"$  with value 2.5; and $x^2_6 = "cat"$  with value 5;